# Ubuntu 16.04 Remote Desktop

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, xrdp, remmina

I installed xRDP in my Ubuntu workstation so that I can access it using my other workstation running Windows OS and it works fine.

Just for security purposes needed in our company, we need to make the remote session just like windows built in RDP, Meaning if in case that I'm accessing my Ubuntu remotely and my co-worker attempts to connect to it. It will prompt me that someone wants to access my Ubuntu just like Windows. Knowing that xRDP supports multiple session, and it may result in security breaches to our company.

If xRDP is not a feasible application for my concern, please advise for any other recommendations and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, I do not think it's possible to have xRDP warn if somebody try to connect to a system while you are connected (out-of-the box) because xRDP by default allows multiple connections.  RDP in microsoft when used against windows workstatioins are limited to one remote connection only (licensing wise)

However, you can limit the number of connection allowed through xRDP.  If you need to ensure that only one user can connect remotely to a specific system, you might wanna check the /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini file and set the max number of connection you might want to authorize

It might be possible to create a script that would monitor number of xrdp sessions and if the session number is above a threshold, you could get a notification....(but never tried that)

Hope this help
Till next time 
See ya